# Grails Quartz2 plugin on Cloudfoundry with multiple instances?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, cloud-foundry

How can I make sure that a cron scheduled Quartz2 job (http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2) is only fired once when my Grails 2 app is running with multiple instances on CloudFoundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a [clustered Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering). The documentation nicely describes how to configure the cluster and `JDBC-JobStore`. You will need a database that all instances can access and synchronize.

According to the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/9ci/grails-quartz2) you should use `Config.groovy` to configure Quartz scheduler as it completely replaces `quartz.properties`.